# adding class to jquery added numbers

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 9 slides are counted by a  that were created in jquery. first slide is 1/9, second one 2/9, and so on...

I need to change only the color of the number that changes in each slide. I thought about adding a class to this single element.

My html:

```
<section class="projects" id="project-1">

  <div class="top-bg">

    <div class="top-header">
      <span class="numbers"></span>
      <h1>Reel 18bis</h1>
    </div>

  </div>
```

and my jQuery:

```
var total = $('.numbers');
    var projects = $('.projects');
    var updateNumbers = function () {
        var currentProjectId = $('.projects.active').attr('id');
        total.html(currentProjectId.replace(/project\-/, '') + '/' + projects.length);
    };
```

Could anyone help?

Comment: seems to be working http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/tpgz7/

Comment: that's hardly a point in adding any classes, since you are identifying each section with an ID.

Comment: wait.. I think I misunderstood what you're trying to do here... if you're going to use jQuery in production.. than just use removeClass and addClass. https://api.jquery.com/removeClass/

Comment: The problem is that I don't want the whole "1/2" to be colored. I want only the "1".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put a quick fiddle together to show how you can use events and the eventArg.targets property as a point of relativity.

I also corrected the projects display 1/2 1/2 with a simple for loop that iterates through the projects property.

http://jsfiddle.net/tpgz7/4/

---

### Javascript

```
(function(window) {
window.ProjectBoard = {
'projects': null,
'total': null,
'updateNumbers': function () {
    for (i=0;i < ProjectBoard.projects.length; i++) {            
        var projID = ProjectBoard.projects[i].getAttribute('id').replace("project\-", "");
        ProjectBoard.total[i].innerHTML ="<span class='number-count'>" + projID + "</span><span class='number-separator'>/</span><span class='number-total'>" + ProjectBoard.total.length + "</span>";           
    }
},
'init': function () {
    ProjectBoard.projects = $('section.projects');
    ProjectBoard.total = $('section.projects span.numbers');
    ProjectBoard.updateNumbers();
    for (i=0;i < ProjectBoard.projects.length; i++) {            
        var projID = ProjectBoard.projects[i].getAttribute('id').replace("project\-", "");
        ProjectBoard.total[i].innerHTML = "<span class='number-count'>" + projID + "</span><span class='number-separator'>/</span><span class='number-total'>" + ProjectBoard.total.length + "</span>";
        /* Attach Event Handlers*/
        ProjectBoard.projects[i].addEventListener('click', function(ev){
            var targetSelector = ev.target.id || ev.target.parentElement.id || ev.target.parentElement.parentElement.id || ev.target.parentElement.parentElement.parentElement.id;            
            $('.active').toggleClass('active');
            $('#'+targetSelector).addClass('active');
        }, false);
    }
}    
};
}(window,document));

ProjectBoard.init(window);
```

*Note that there is a small (and unnecessary) dependency on jQuery selectors in the 'init' method. querySelectorAll(".projects") would work just as well here.. Also there is a $().css assignment method, which could be replaced with $element$.style.color = %value%, respectfully.*

---

### HTML

```
<section class="projects active" id="project-1">
    <div class="top-bg">
        <div class="top-header"> <span class="numbers"></span>
            <h1>Reel 18bis</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section class="projects" id="project-2">
    <div class="top-bg">
        <div class="top-header"> <span class="numbers"></span>
            <h1>Reel 18bis</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section class="projects" id="project-3">
    <div class="top-bg">
        <div class="top-header"> <span class="numbers"></span>
             <h1>Reel 18bis</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section class="projects" id="project-4">
    <div class="top-bg">
        <div class="top-header"> <span class="numbers"></span>
             <h1>Reel 18bis</h1>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
```

---

### CSS

```
section.projects 
{
    border:0.2em solid black;
    margin-bottom:0.2em;
    position:relative;
    display:block;
    padding:1.2em;
}

section.projects span.numbers 
{
    position:absolute;right:-0.2em;
    padding:0.35em;
    display:block;
    top:-0.2em;
    color:#202020;
    background-color:whitesmoke;
    border:0.2em solid silver;
    font-weight:700;
}

body section.projects.active span.numbers 
{
    color: black;
    backround-color:gray;
    top:-0.2em;right:-0.2em;
    border:0.2em solid black;
}

 body section.projects.active span.numbers span.number-count
{
    font-size: 2em;
    color: lime;
}
```

---

Comment: Hey @BrettCaswell thanks for the answer. But the problem is that I don't want the whole "1/2" to be colored. I want only the "1". So I need to find a way to separate the "currentProjectId.replace(/project\-/, '') " from the "+ '/' + projects.length". Sorry if I described it in a wy that sounded confusing

Comment: I see this question has been closed, but to address your last point of inquiry.. the innerHTML property refers to DOM manipulation, so instead of assigning projID + / + ProjectBoard.total.length.. you could assign "<span class='whatever'>" + projID + "</span>" + "/" + ProjectBoard.total.length ... that way you can use css styling, or selectors, on the span.whatever element.